# Memory leak in python interactive shell

Tags: python, memory-leaks, ubuntu-12.04

When I run the python 2.7 interactive shell (in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) I get what appears to be a memory leak. When I launch an interactive shell, the memory usage steps up at a fairly even rate until all the ram (3.9gb) is used, then it knocks back to 80% (ish) and swap space jumps up by ~200-400mb and it levels off and offers the prompt, but any further interaction pushes the RAM usage back to 100% where it stays (rendering the system pretty much inoperable).

The interactive shell can be launched from a gnome terminal, or when ssh'd into the computer from another box (I was testing using connectbot for android), and the same problem occurs.

**EDIT**:
I removed my .pythonrc.py file and the problem seems to have disappeared. I did not change it recently (I created it a month ago and haven't touched it since, this problem started yesterday).

Here is my pythonrc file (`.pythonrc.py`)

```
import atexit 
import os 
import readline 
import rlcompleter 

history = os.path.expanduser('~/.python_history') 
readline.read_history_file(history) 
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete') 
atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, history)
```

**EDIT 2:**

I deleted my `.python_history` file and that seems to have fixed the problem. The file was 1914155 lines and around 54mb. I intend to adjust my .pythonrc file so that it will only store a history of a couple hundred lines.

Comment: You might want to add more information about *what* you're trying to accomplish, just running Python interactively isn't enough.

Comment: Are you typing any commands, or just letting it sit there?

Comment: I am not typing commands, all I do is launch the interactive shell it doesn't matter what I try and do in the shell.

Comment: How did you accumulate 1.9 million lines of history??

Comment: I wish I could tell you... Probably due to the file being at least a year old and a lot of reusing previous blocks of lines as I test out functions. But finding out that it was that many lines boggles my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the problem (hopefully a permanent solution), I added the following line to the `.pythonrc.py` file.

```
import atexit 
import os 
import readline 
import rlcompleter 

history = os.path.expanduser('~/.python_history') 
readline.read_history_file(history) 
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
# The added line
readline.set_history_length(200)
atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, history)
```

I assume that any sufficiently not stupidly large number will be fine (instead of just 200), but I figure that if I am going more than 200 lines back in my history I am doing something wrong.